# What is the best way to count user time between rounds while playing game

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, timer

I'm developing a game, where people can select some ingredients and try to cook. When they select ingredients from the list they can click on "cook" button and the list of selected products is sent to the server with ajax, it take some time and after that they receive message that it was okay or the list is wrong. If list is okay they pass the level, game is loading next level.

During the game time is running. What is the best way to count the time that user needed to select proper elements from the list including all that delays during the requests and etc..

Right now I'm sending the time that user clicks the button and it's being compared with the time measured in PHP requested file. The difference is subtracted and returned to user.
I don't want to use that kind of solution cause people can cheat (by editing measured time in javascript).

Workflow:
User click start -> time starts -> select elements -> cook -> okay -> load next level (also async) -> start next level -> remember time from previous level and start from the same place -> select elements -> cook -> okay -> end -> show time

Comment: take a look at http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Answer (score 0):

when you start/stop timer, you should make an ajax call and the server should measure the time. store it in a session.

Comment: it's working like that right now, i mean, measured time is stored in session but how to measure the delay between the requests..?

Comment: well, you need the difference between the two times

Comment: don't send the click time. send something like 'start' and save the return value of PHP time() function